# Permissions to be stored as a Node or a property

Tags: neo4j, database-schema, graph-databases

We have six different types of permissions for content nodes. If we want to query neo4j for the content by the permission type, is it better to store the permissions as an attribute for each content node, or as a separate node to which each piece of content has a relationship?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good data modeling question, and the truth is it depends.

I'm personally in favor of storing them as a separate node, so you don't have to traverse all nodes(or at least all user nodes) in order to find all the permissions you are looking for, especially if you start to get a lot of users and will be looking for all users of permission X.

This also adds a level of normalization, as well as the ability to perform counts easily.

Comment: I agree with you and thats why I was kind of inkling towards making them as node. However do you think of any flip sides of using it this way?

Comment: The down side is that eventually you will run into a dense node problem, which is a node with too many relationships making traversal across it very hard. But you'll only run into this when you start having a node with relationships past a several hundred thousand.